# geom_area in ggplot, qplot behaving very bizarrely. No similar trouble with geom_line, geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a subset of the data which demonstrates the problem.

```
dat <- structure(list(days = structure(c(16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 
16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 
16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 16784, 16785, 
16785, 16785, 16785, 16785, 16785, 16785, 16785, 16785, 16785
), class = "Date"), amount = c(88321.19, 88341.19, 88361.19, 
88386.19, 88406.19, 88606.19, 88646.19, 88686.19, 88736.19, 88786.19, 
88806.19, 88836.19, 88871.19, 88896.19, 88921.19, 88971.19, 88996.19, 
89068.36, 89098.36, 89148.36, 89248.36, 89348.36, 89369.16, 89469.16, 
89493.68, 89518.68, 89568.68, 89618.68, 89658.68, 89683.68, 89708.68
)), .Names = c("days", "amount"), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dat,aes(x=days, y=amount)) + geom_area()
```

Running this, I see A line with decreasing slope, which is clearly contrary to the data.

[image: a line with decreaing slope]

Even replacing `+ geom_area()` with `+ geom_ribbon(data=exampleDat, aes(ymin=0, ymax=amount))`
 produces the right picture (a roughly flat black box). Likewise for `geom_line()`.

When the entire dataset is graphed, I get the plot (the axes refer to the same variables as before, both nondecreasing) here:

[image: plot with more days].

Any insight would be hugely appreciated. I've never had this problem occur before.

Comment: Check out your y-axis. `geom_area` is summing the data for each day, because you're passing it a lot of points for each—but more for the 15th.

Comment: Interesting. geom_area handles the data differently than geom_line and geom_ribbon!

Thanks! It's a lot unnecessary data anyway, so I'll do 1 point per day. Looks like it will work. Though I'm not sure I understand why it drops to ~0 for the 16th.